# How to elegantly resize rectangles with optionally keeping aspect ratio

Tags: geometry, resize, 2d, rectangles

I would like to resize rectangles in a two dimensional coordinate system (starting at 0,0 with a maximum size of 1000, 1000) using a computer mouse.
This should not be very complicated and I already have a brief solution for it:

**pseudocode**

```
function setSize(shape, anchor)
    mouseX, mouseY = GetCursorPosition();

    if (anchor == "LEFT") then
        diff = math.abs(mouseX - shape.left);

        if (shape.left > mouseX) then
            shape.width = shape.width + diff
        else
            shape.width = shape.width - diff
        end
    elseif (anchor == "TOPLEFT") then
        diffX = math.abs(mouseX - shape.left);
        diffY = math.abs(mouseY - shape.top);

        if (shape.left > mouseX) then
            shape.width = spahe.width + diffX
        else
            shape.width = shape.width - diffX
        end

        if (shape.top > mouseY) then
            shape.height = shape.height - diffY
        else
            shape.height = shape.height + diffY
        end
    elseif (anchor == "TOP") then
        diffY = math.abs(mouseY - shape.top);

        if (shape.top > mouseY) then
            shape.height = shape.height - diffY
        else
            shape.height = shape.height + diffY
        end
    elseif (anchor == "TOPRIGHT") then
        diffX = math.abs(mouseX - shape.right);
        diffY = math.abs(mouseY - shape.top);

        if (shape.right > mouseX) then
            shape.width = shape.width - diffX
        else
            shape.width = spahe.width + diffX
        end

        if (shape.top > mouseY) then
            shape.height = shape.height - diffY
        else
            shape.height = shape.height + diffY
        end
    elseif (anchor == "RIGHT") then
        diffX = math.abs(mouseX - shape.right);

        if (shape.right > mouseX) then
            shape.width = shape.width - diffX
        else
            shape.width = spahe.width + diffX
        end
    elseif (anchor == "BOTTOMRIGHT") then
        diffX = math.abs(mouseX - shape.right);
        diffY = math.abs(mouseY - shape.bottom);

        if (shape.right > mouseX) then
            shape.width = shape.width - diffX
        else
            shape.width = spahe.width + diffX
        end

        if (shape.bottom > mouseY) then
            shape.height = shape.height + diffY
        else
            shape.height = shape.height - diffY
        end
    elseif (anchor == "BOTTOM") then
        diffY = math.abs(mouseY - shape.bottom);

        if (shape.bottom > mouseY) then
            shape.height = shape.height + diffY
        else
            shape.height = shape.height - diffY
        end
    elseif (anchor == "BOTTOMLEFT") then
        diffX = math.abs(mouseX - shape.left);
        diffY = math.abs(mouseY - shape.bottom);

        if (shape.left > mouseX) then
            shape.width = spahe.width + diffX
        else
            shape.width = shape.width - diffX
        end

        if (shape.bottom > mouseY) then
            shape.height = shape.height + diffY
        else
            shape.height = shape.height - diffY
        end
    end
end
```

Whats missing in the code is the repositioning of the rectangle and also the support for optionally keeping the aspect ratio of the rectangle. Even though there are already a lot of ifs and elses in the above code there would be much more of them including the repositioning and the aspect ratio.

Im sure there must be a very elegant way to do all that but my math is way too weak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is `startpos` (perhaps your anchor) and current mouse position `(X,Y)`. Sample rectangle has dimensions `(sw, sh)` (for example, 320x240).

Result rectangle has left top corner position `(rx0, ry0)` and size `rw, rh`

```
  nw = X - startpos.x
  nh = Y - startpos.y
  anw = Abs(nw)
  anh = Abs(nh)

  if anw * sh < anh * sw:
      rh = anh
      rw = rh * sw // sh     #integer division if important
      ry0 = Min(Y, startpos.y)
      rx0 = Min(startpos.x, startpos.x + rw * Sign(nw))
  else:
      rw = anw
      rh = rw * sh // sw
      rx0 = Min(X, startpos.x)
      ry0 = Min(startpos.y, startpos.y + rh * Sign(nh))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi. Thx for the reply. Is the `//` ("double slash") a special operator or is it simple division?

Comment: I used it as integer division in Python-like pseudocode (perhaps you don't need to care aboit int/floats)